# doh of dojo is not working with sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo, sinon, doh

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313624/how-to-load-a-js-file-that-is-not-a-module-in-dojo) solution, it not works well.

Here is the example code from the link above:

```
require([
    "doh/runner",
    "http://sinonjs.org/releases/sinon-1.17.5.js"
], function(doh){
    console.log(sinon);
});
```

Error message:

```
$ node ../../dojo/dojo.js load=doh test=tests/test_sinon_spy.js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'http://sinonjs.org/releases/sinon-1.17.5.js'
```

---

Besides this, I also try to require sinon.js directly.

*`sinon-1.17.5.js` have been moved to the directory `doh` which is as same as `runner.js`, and renamed to `sinon`. (The directory )*

```
require([
    "doh/runner",
    "doh/sinon"
], function(doh, sinon){
    console.log(sinon);
});
```

There is no error message, but sinon is undefined:

```
$ node ../../dojo/dojo.js load=doh test=tests/test_sinon_spy.js
undefined
0 'tests to run in' 0 'groups'
------------------------------------------------------------
| TEST SUMMARY:
------------------------------------------------------------
         0 tests in 0 groups
         0 errors
         0 failures
```

---

I am pretty sure that the second code loads sinon well. I verified that by modifying `sinon.js` directly. But I have no idea why sinon is not able to call.

---

Version

```
node.js - v6.2.2
dojo/doh - 1.10.0
sinon - 1.17.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[UPDATED]**

Because both `node.js` and `dojo` have **require API**, but they are different. This case is not working because it should use node.js's API to require `sinon.js` rather than dojo's API.

Dojo provide the [dojo/node](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/node.html) module, it will call node.js module directly.

**1. Install sinon by npm under same directory of dojo**

```
$ cd ../../dojo
$ npm install sinon
```

**2. Modify the code to use dojo/node**

```
# test_sinon_spy.js
require([
    "doh/runner",
    "dojo/node!sinon"
], function(doh, sinon){
    console.log(sinon);
})
```

**3. Back to original folder and run the test**

```
$ cd -
$ node ../../dojo/dojo.js load=doh test=tests/test_sinon_spy.js
```

*Note, under dojo directory, it will contain npm_module/sinon*